# Chrome Extension error: “Unchecked runtime.lastError while running browserAction.setIcon: Icon invalid."

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was trying to change Chrome extension icon dynamically by following this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction#method-setIcon).

Unfortunately, it is not working with the following code:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: 'my_icon.png'});
```

In console, it is failing with following error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running browserAction.setIcon: Icon invalid.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After reading elsewhere on the web, I found that we need to specify images with size either (or both) of **19x19 px** or **38x38 px**.

So I resized my icon image, and made 2 copies of it as follows:

- my_icon-19.png
- my_icon-38.png

Now when I tried the following code, it worked as expected:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: { "19": "/images/my_icon-19.png",
                                       "38": "/images/my_icon-38.png" } });
```

You do not need both of the versions to make it work, so following would work as well:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({ path: "/images/my_icon-38.png" });
```

Comment: A bit of heads-up, soon(-ish) Chrome will [switch to 16 and 32 as action icon sizes](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=546206). May as well add them already (Chrome accepts those sizes as well).

Comment: @Xan Thanks for the heads up. I haven't tried those sizes yet. But on latest version of Chrome (51.0.2704.106), the 19 and 38 seems to be working fine.

Comment: I am on Mac OS X El Capitan. 

On other hand, I suppose they would downscale the 19x19 to 16x16 if they really need to, so as not to break the live extensions.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what they are doing, and it looks exactly as bad as it sounds.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, resizing it with 128px*128px, with resolution of 72px/inches, worked for me.

Prior to that I tried with 512px and 256px proportions

[image: image dimension reference]

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error. I fixed it after I resized the icon much lot smaller. My original icon was 200px by 200px and the one that worked was 100px by 100px.